# Xcode 15 build failed on react native 14 iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build

If you could help us in this matter it would be a great support and highly appreciated. we are using Xcode 15 to make an iOS app from react native. The React native version is 0.64.4 and the app was previously built two or three years ago by another team. now the app development is handed to us, but we couldn’t even run the app from a simulator.

As we know Xcode 15 with SDK iOS 17/17.2 doesn’t seem to support our app.
and the iOS targetting version is 11 for our app. However, we don’t know what kind of computer or Xcode version they previously used to do this. intel 86_64 or Apple silicon, but we use Apple silicon one.

For react native, the node version is 14, and the Java version is 8.

Our system is a Macbook Air M1.

We can’t update our app at this moment and need to make a few changes, add some fixes, and publish the version to the App Store, then soon, we are hoping to upgrade our React native version because we had to fix our dependency version errors. it will take some time, but for now, we had to publish this as it is.

Thank you for any help! Thank you again!

Tried changing the iOS development target to 17, but it didn't solve it. The Android build was running and working fine. only the iOS development is not working. tried react-native 0.72.10 using Xcode and it successfully built that app.

Comment: did you fix your probleme ?

Comment: @AlainIb , still no. trying different methods.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  

For example you can't run the app from a simulator - why? what happened please share some diagnostics/error messages/etc.

Comment: @Evan Anger, OK. I'll be more specific. Thanks. Attaching error messages.